# Placing random values in array

Tags: c

I'm new to coding and debugging. As an assignment I'm trying to make a Nim game for two players. However whenever I reach a point in my code it give me a segmentation fault. I thought the problem would be something as pointing to a wrong place in an array, but changing those values did not help. Eventually I tried to debug using gdb, and it said that I had a segmentation fault at the line where I assign a random number to the array. I wouldn't know what to do with the information I got while debugging though. Here's the part where I assign random numbers from 1 to 6 into an array:

```
for (int x; x < aantalrijen; x++) {
    if (geinitialiseerd == 0) {
        fiches[x] = rand()% 6 + 1 ;
        geinitialiseerd = 1;
    }
    printf("\n\tRij %d:\t", x+1);
        for (int y = 0; y < fiches[x]; y++) {
            printf(" @ ");
        }
    fichesum = fichesum + fiches[x];
}
}
```

Surprisingly enough I only get the segmentation fault if I enter a 1 or a 10 as aantalrijen, but not when I enter anything inbetween. However the code still doesn;t work as it should when I do enter a number from 2 to 9. This is the entire code I have written up to now, even though it's not complete yet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Initialiseren van speler namen, wiens beurt het is, de aantal rijen, 
de aantal fiches op ieder rij, het totaal aantal fiches en de variant 
die gespeeld wordt.
char speler1[10];
char speler2[10];
int geinitialiseerd;
int beurt;
int aantalrijen;
int fiches[10];
int fichesum;
int rijnemen;
int aantalnemen;
int variant;

int output () {

//For loop voor initialisatie van het spel. Hiermee wordt bedoelt dat x aantal rijen een random waarde krijgen tussen 1 en 6. Deze worden ook meteen geprint.
    for (int x; x < aantalrijen; x++) {
        if (geinitialiseerd == 0) {
            fiches[x] = rand()% 6 + 1 ;
            geinitialiseerd = 1;
        }
        printf("\n\tRij %d:\t", x+1);
            for (int y = 0; y < fiches[x]; y++) {
                printf(" @ ");
            }
        fichesum = fichesum + fiches[x];
    }
}

int main () {

//Introductie en vraag om namen
printf("==========================================================================================\n**Welkom bij Nim! Dit is een spel gemaakt door Michael Francis voor twee spelers!\t**\n==========================================================================================\n**Wat is de naam van speler 1?\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t**\n");
scanf("%s", &speler1);
printf("**Wat is de naam van speler 2?\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t**\n");
scanf("%s", &speler2);
printf("\n**Kies het aantal rijen waarmee u wilt spelen (tussen de 1 en 10):\t\t\t**\n==========================================================================================\n");
scanf("%d", &aantalrijen);
printf("==========================================================================================\n**Kies de variant die u wilt spelen:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t**\n\t1. Verliezer neemt laatste fiche\n\t2. Winnaar neemt laatste fiche\n==========================================================================================\n");
scanf("%d", &variant);
printf("==========================================================================================\n**Nieuw gegenereerd spel:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t**\n");
output();
printf("\n\n==========================================================================================\n");
fichesum = 100;
while (fichesum != 0) {

    //For-loop om huidige fiches uit te printen
    //for (int a; a < aantalrijen; a++) {
    //  printf("\n\tRij %d:\t", a+1);
    //  for (int b = 0; b < fiches[a]; b++) {
    //      printf(" @ ");
    //  }
    //}
    output();

    fichesum = 0;
    if (beurt == 0) {
        printf("\n\n==========================================================================================\n%s is aan de beurt!", speler1);
        beurt = 1;
    } else {
        printf("\n\n==========================================================================================\n%s is aan de beurt!", speler2);
        beurt = 0;
    }
    printf("\nUit welk rij wilt u fiches nemen?\n");
    scanf("%d", &rijnemen - 1);
    printf("\nHoeveel fiches wilt u nemen?\n");
    scanf("%d", &aantalnemen);
    fiches[rijnemen] = fiches[rijnemen] - aantalnemen;
    printf("%d", fiches[rijnemen]);

}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile with `-Wall -O2`, you'd get a warning on the `for` loop in `output`:

```
dut.c: In function ‘output’:
dut.c:21:11: warning: ‘x’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  for (int x; x < aantalrijen; x++) {
           ^
```

Change:

```
for (int x; x < aantalrijen; x++) {
```

Into:

```
for (int x = 0; x < aantalrijen; x++) {
```

---

Another warning to fix

Change:

```
    scanf("%s", &speler1);
    scanf("%s", &speler2);
```

Into:

```
    scanf("%s", speler1);
    scanf("%s", speler2);
```